# Sql one to many relationship

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

In my application I have the following Clients, Products. I want for each Client to have certain Products( one to many relationship) my code :

Tables Creation :

```
Create Table Client 
(
IDC int identity(1,1) not null primary key,
NumeC nvarchar(50),
CIF nvarchar(50) unique
)
Create Table Produs
(
IDP int identity(1,1) not null,
NumeP nvarchar(50),
Cantitate int,
IDC int 
)
```

this the Foreign Key :

```
Alter table Produs add constraint FK_Client_Produs_IDC
Foreign key (IDC) references Client(IDC)
```

Select statement Query to join Clients and foreach client to show Products :

```
Select NumeC,CIF from Client
Inner Join Produs
ON Client.IDC = Produs.IDC
```

I don't know what am I doing wrong, I just want to show Products for each client. It does not give me that. It just repeats the name of the client, now showing me The products for each client

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `SELECT` you don't ever include anything from the `Produs` table, so why would it show it to you.

```
Select NumeC,CIF,NumeP
from Client
Inner Join Produs
ON Client.IDC = Produs.IDC
```

Comment: Yes thank you, but It will show me the name of the clients for each product. Example: 1 DataGridView1 for Clients and Another DataGridView2 for products from that Client separate. When you click a row in DataGridView1 to Display Products in DataGridView2 corresponding to the client chosen in DataGridView1(ROW).

Comment: What you need is to write `on click` or `on press` event in DataGridView1 that will query database for all products that are related to that Client. This is completely outside of scope of your original question.

Comment: Yes I know, I will mark it as answer but I have another problem, I will have History of Clients and Products, as you see CIF is unique. So when the Click Event in dataGridView1 how do I know what to put in the Where Clause Select NumeC,CIF,NumeP
from Client
Inner Join Produs
ON Client.IDC = Produs.IDC where CIF = 'RO2' I mean the history will repeat the same client with different products how to select the one accordingly ?

Comment: You need to ask another question and word it accordingly with that information. It will be too lengthy to answer this in comments, additionally it is outside of scope of this question to be involved in this discussion.